# In which classpath should .jar of mysql-connector-java-5.1.38 be included

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat8

I have no idea as to where to include the .jar file of mysql-connector/j using tomcat8.0.33. One of the blogs have mentioned to include in $CATALINA_HOME/common/lib, but i am not able to find "common".
And also could anyone please tell me how to create context configuration file for tomcat.

Comment: copy it to $TOMCAT\lib folder.but that depends where to connection are to be managed.

Answer (score 0):

In the $CATALINA_HOME/conf, examine the catalina.properties file. There are definitions for where it will look for .jar files.

You can make the directory $CATALINA_HOME/common/lib, but it also must be loaded in one of the loaders defined in that .properties file. We actually make the common/lib, and modify the .properties, but there are differences of opinion on that approach.

You should also be aware of some differences in the loading because of the class loaders that are used by the different defined loaders.

I believe you are safe (in terms of it being found) in placing the MySQL library in the $catalina_base/lib directory, which I believe is included by default in the common.loader.

Comment: Yes, I have done it. Anymore changes needed. Can anyone tell me what is this all about.

Comment: 1) Create a context configuration file for Tomcat.
Create a configuration file in your $CATALINA_HOME/conf/ which has the file name apps-yourapp.xml
Eg: If your applications name is myapp then,
$ vi /var/tomcat/conf/apps-myapps.xml                                                                                            2) Enter the things found here or in this file. When you copy and paste these code, please remember to replace values for Context path, docBase, Resource name, ResourceParams name, username, password and url with your values.

Answer (score 0):

Copy it to `$TOMCAT\lib` folder.but that depends where to connection are to be managed.